# Problem with MoveGroupInterface::getRobotModel() providing only const version

Tags: ros, robot-model, move-group-interface, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get my own instance of JointModelGroup from code equivalent to this:

```
auto move_group = moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface {"panda_arm"};
auto robot_model_constptr = move_group.getRobotModel();
auto joint_model_group = std::unique_ptr<moveit::core::JointModelGroup> {robot_model_constptr->getJointModelGroup("panda_arm")};
```

However this doesn't compile (long error omitted for brevity):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<moveit::core::JointModelGroup>::unique_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   auto joint_model_group = std::unique_ptr<moveit::core::JointModelGroup> {robot_model_constptr->getJointModelGroup("panda_arm")};
```

which ultimately boils down to

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<moveit::core::JointModelGroup>::pointer {aka moveit::core::JointModelGroup*}’ [-fpermissive]
   auto joint_model_group = std::unique_ptr<moveit::core::JointModelGroup> {robot_model_constptr->getJointModelGroup("panda_arm")};
```

This stems apparently from `getRobotModel` either being a const function or returning a ConstPtr (likely the first), as that leads to calling the const version of `getJointModelGroup` (instead of the existing non-const) which makes it impossible to get the unique_ptr.

I have found however that this does compile:

```
auto move_group = moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface {"panda_arm"};
auto robot_model_constptr = move_group.getRobotModel();
auto robot_model = * robot_model_constptr;
auto joint_model_group = std::unique_ptr<moveit::core::JointModelGroup> {robot_model.getJointModelGroup("panda_arm")};
```

and I'm therefore left wondering if I'm doing something I shouldn't or if there is a better way to get joint_model_group without declaring things I don't necessarily need myself.

EDIT: from what I can gather e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239630/trouble-with-const-non-const-overload-resolution) I get the const version of `getJointModelGroup` because `getRobotModel` is const, is what I'm trying to say.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312774/problem-with-movegroupinterface::getrobotmodel()-providing-only-const-version/) by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 589 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't remember how or why but I remember having tried and having it not work. Regardless, this does work:

```
auto joint_model_group = std::make_unique<moveit::core::JointModelGroup>(*robot_model_constptr->getJointModelGroup("panda_arm"));
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853309/whats-wrong-with-this-initialization-of-unique-ptr))

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0